# is there an easier way to write call to format

Tags: racket

is there a simpler way to write the following code?

```
(format "~a ~a ~a" (first l) (second l) (third l))
```

Here `l` is always of length 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify format string directly, but don't want to write `first`, `second`, `third`, then:

```
(apply format "~a ~a ~a" l)
```

If you want to `~a` "regularly" on all elements of the list, then you can write:

```
(string-join (map ~a l) " ")
```